# > Could not find any matches for com.facebook.react:react-native:+ as no versions of com.facebook.react:react-native are available

Tags: react-native

There was apparently a RN outage. This causes so much issues now as I can get a build out.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

but that "FIX" says to look at [https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210#:~:text=We%20have%20prepared%20releases%20for%20all%20the%20main%20versions%20of%20react%2Dnative%20with%20an%20hotfix%3A](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210#:%7E:text=We%20have%20prepared%20releases%20for%20all%20the%20main%20versions%20of%20react%2Dnative%20with%20an%20hotfix%3A)

The issue with that is there is no mention of 0.71.0-RC.0 version fix, I am on that version and when I try to run npx react-native run-android, I get the following:

```
   > Could not find any matches for com.facebook.react:react-native:+ as no versions of com.facebook.react:react-native are available.
```

If someone came across this could you please mention how you solved this? I do not understand what the fix is for my situation specifically.

This is what the terminal spits out when I run react-native info:

```
System:
OS: macOS 13.0
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
Memory: 129.47 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 16.14.2 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
npm: 8.5.5 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
Watchman: 2022.09.05.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
  Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 16.0, macOS 12.3, tvOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2021.2 AI-212.5712.43.2112.8815526
Xcode: 14.0.1/14A400 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 11.0.16.1 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
react-native: 0.71.0-rc.0 => 0.71.0-rc.0 
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found
```

please let me know if I should add more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by upgrading my RN version to one of the ones with the patches

Comment: which is what exactly...?

Comment: follow this link: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

Comment: I read that. Unfortunately, this is Chinese to me. I did a `npx react-native upgrade` to upgrade the project to latest ReactNative, got a bunch of errors (unclear why). My package.json contains     `"react": "18.2.0",     "react-native": "0.71.0",`  and that page mainly talks about < 0.71... Hmm

Comment: could you try upgrading to one of the specific versions?, I upgraded too "0.75.5"

Comment: hmm I thought npx react-native upgrade upgrade to the latest, and it became 0.71. Do I need to specify 0.75.5 manually? It says "info No version passed. Fetching latest...
warn Specified version "0.71.0" is already installed in node_modules and it satisfies "0.71.0" semver range. No need to upgrade"

Comment: I had to specify manually yes

Comment: How? I got this error: _info Fetching diff between v0.71.0 and v0.75.5...
error Fetch request failed with status 404: 404: Not Found.
error Failed to fetch diff for react-native@0.75.5. Maybe it's not released yet?_

Comment: 0.71 is latest, 0.75.5 does not exist: https://reactnative.dev/versions

Comment: ahh i made a typo sorry, its 0.70.5

Comment: Well, upgrading to 0.70.5 instead got passed that error. That is kinda crazy (I think).

Answer (score 2):

Just to be sure everyone gets this, yes @Grant Solomons got this right.

So if in your `package.json` file you have `"react-native": "^0.70.0",`, delete the `^` it to `"react-native": "0.70.0",`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after upgrading to React Native 0.71, and this solution worked for me.

1. Open `android/app/build.gradle` file (Not `android/build.gradle` file)
2. Add `apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"` like this:

> apply plugin: "com.android.application"
>
> **apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"**
>
> import com.android.build.OutputFile

3. Rebuild your application, it should works

Answer (score 1):

My APP is based on RN 0.64.3 , I fixed it with `android/buld.gradle`

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
```

ref to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210