# Fails to build project on another local machine from repository - Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment

Tags: react-native

So I have existing react-native project and it works and builds fine ok on one local machine.
I pushed the project to repository, but it fails to build on another machine.

So I cloned the project from repository on another machine:

did `npm-install`

then I tried `npx react-native start` but it was missing 4 choices with "open Android app", instead it only shows two (without ios and android) so i tried `npx react-native run-android` instead but it fails with

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.facebook.react:react-android:.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.facebook.react:hermes-android:.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

If I delete `node_modules` (it's ignored by Git) folder and copy `node_modules` from the first local machine then it works fine and `npx react-native start` detects ios and android apps can compiles them fine.

Content of **perk_sample.json**:

```
{
  "name": "nameofapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

please ask me to add any other info if needed

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded RN with `npx react-native upgrade` based on info from https://stackoverflow.com/a/74436820/7767664

Now it's

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.2"
```

Now `npx react-native start` works fine now and I can see 4 choices and it builds as well (though not from the first try after all manipulations, re-running helped, but then again tried clean build and works from the first try)

Glad I'm a native dev and it's just a temporary project :)

Also had a problem that I was excluding `gradle-wrapper.jar` (was added to `gitignore`) and react-native could not download it itself with gradle (though Android Studio doesn't need this file on the repository, it can download it itself with gradle based on url at `gradle-wrapper.properties`):

```
info Installing the app...
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```