# Could not find com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.4. Required by: project :app project

Tags: react-native, gradle, react-android

I am trying to update my react native version because I'm still on version 69 and want to be on the latest, 73.4

I have also updated my gradle to 8.2.2 to stay up with the times, and think I'm close, but am seeing this build error:

Could not find com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.4.

in my build.gradle in android/app I have

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.4"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:hermes-android:0.73.4"
...
}
```

but am still seeing

```
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:devDebugCompileClasspath'. > Could not find com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.4. Required by: project :app project :app > project :react-native-restart project :app > project :react-native-firebase_app project :app > project :react-native-firebase_crashlytics > Could not find com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.4. Required by: project :app > Could not find com.facebook.react:hermes-android:0.73.4. Required by: project :app * Try:
```

Comment: same here, i dont know why react-native updates are bad that much

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74430295/could-not-find-any-matches-for-com-facebook-reactreact-native-as-no-version